# Setting session variables vs setting variable in browser cookie (Django app)

Tags: django, session, cookies

I need to clear a concept.

I'm tracking unauthenticated users in my Django social networking web-app via setting a `temp_id` that's set in the `request.session` dictionary as soon as a new user hits the web-app's landing page. The code is is simply:

```
temp_id = request.session.get('temp_id',None)
if not temp_id:
    request.session['temp_id'] = get_temp_id()
```

So far so good.

Apart from saving a temp_id in `request.session`, another technique I could have used is setting a browser cookie explicitly for unauthenticated users like so:

```
if not request.session.exists(request.session.session_key):
    request.session.create()
```

The concept I'd like to clarify is **are these approaches equivalent**?

I feel they are. My reasoning is: if a browser cookie is just a reference to a `Session` stored in the DB, then if cookies were turned off, matching a `Session` for that user would be impossible. So regardless of whichever approach I take, I'll be relying on the *browser's ability to store a cookie*.

Or in other words, both methods of allotting a `temp_id` to an unauthenticated user are, under the hood, quite similar. The only difference is that browser cookies are less secure than session variables (over `HTTPS`).

Can someone point out whether this line of thinking is correct? Or is my approach wrong? I'm essentially trying to ascertain which approach to take for reliably tracking unauthenticated users once they hit my app's landing page and move about.